# Can you copy / migrate a list from Sharepoint 2007 to 2013 without third party software?

Tags: custom-list, migration, metadata

I am curious if its possible to migrate a huge list from 2007 to 2013 and keeping metadata without going through 2010 first or using third party software?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stay in supported mode from MSFT then you have only two options.

- migrate from 2007 to 2010 to 2013
- Or use the 3rd party tool.

But their is one un supported way, But i am not sure whether it works from 2007 to 2013.
Read the instruction from the below blog( this is from 2010 to 2013) but you can change the version from 12 to 15.

Method 1 is the option you may try.
http://absolute-sharepoint.com/2013/08/how-to-move-a-list-from-sharepoint-2010-to-sharepoint-2013.html